# Terminal tool to join mp4 videos

Tags: video, mp4

I would like to join mp4 videos like I join pdfs by `pdfjoin`.

**Is there any default tool to join videos?**

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, you can join multiple videos into one file using default terminal commands. Using a simple `cat` will do want you want.

```
cat video1.avi video2.avi videon.avi > output.avi
```

There is a big but here - this method will output the `video1.avi` header onto `output.avi`. Therefore, the header of `output.avi` is the same as `video1.avi`, so on most video players, it will look like `video2.avi` and `videon.avi` are lost - [source 1](http://www.mactricksandtips.com/2011/01/join-avi-or-other-movie-files-together.html), [source 2](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20101105030030245).

To fix this, you need additional tools. There are many other terminal tools for joining movies that update the header as well. The most known video editing tools are [`mencoder`](http://www.mplayerhq.hu) (which is a part of MPlayer) and [`ffmpeg`](http://www.ffmpeg.org). Both have an enormous amount of options and settings and it is beyond this forum to go into much detail, but I will give the short commands below.

The use and installation of `mencoder` or `ffmpeg` can be intimidating, but the video editing capabilities are the most powerful I have encountered so far. As the installation from source can be a hassle for native OS X users, I advise you to use [Homebrew](https://brew.sh).

To install these tools using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh), run this one-liner in your terminal:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)"
```

Homebrew is now installed, it is wise to follow the installer's suggestions after installation. Now we install `ffmpeg` and `mencoder` using `brew`.

```
brew install ffmpeg mplayer
```

Now we can use `mencoder` to merge the two videos:

```
mencoder -oac copy -ovc copy -idx -o output.mp4 video1.mp4 video2.mp4 video3.mp4
```

Or we can use `ffmpeg` to merge the two videos:

```
ffmpeg -i concat:"video1.mp4|video2.mp4" -codec copy output.mp4
```

Note that you may need to escape the character "`|`" which is special for many shells, so

```
ffmpeg -i concat:video1.mp4\|video2.mp4
```

You specifically ask for `.mp4` files. `mp4` is a container format, it is possible that the default installation of `ffmpeg` or `mencoder` does not have the correct coding/decoding ('codecs') packages by default and that you need to install these separately. But that is beyond the scope of this topic.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118616/discussion-on-answer-by-cousincocaine-terminal-tool-to-join-mp4-videos).

Answer (score 8):

The first answer above didn't work for a recent version of ffmpeg, which would be 5 years now since this answer was given.

So in order to do a simple concatenation of video files without re-encoding them using a modern version of ffmpeg (currently 4.4.1):

Create a .txt file with each line containing the files you want to concatenate, and each filename needs to be preceded by the word file and the filename needs to be surrounded by tick-marks. It should end up looking like this:

```
file 'Video1.mov'
file 'Video2.mov'
file 'Video3.mov'
```

Also, if you're running the ffmpeg command from the same folder that your files and the text file exist in, then no need to worry about using absolute paths in the text file.

Save that file as whatever ... I called mine files.txt.

Then this command will join them together and put the result into a single video file:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i files.txt -c copy VideoFinal.mov
```

If you need to use absolute paths in your text file, then you would OMIT the -safe 0 from the command like so:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i files.txt -c copy VideoFinal.mov
```

This worked like a champ for me and it joined a couple of hundred megs of video in less than three seconds.