# Does Mac offer a way to return video specs in terminal without ffmpeg?

Tags: macos, terminal, video

I was curious to know if there is a way in Mac terminal to return a video's details similar to sips is for images on the Mac before I [install ffmpeg](https://superuser.com/questions/854793/how-to-install-ffmpeg-on-os-x)?  I am currently using Yosemite so if there an alternative has been developed for Yosemite for getting video specs through terminal other than ffmpeg or [ffprobe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684015/how-can-i-get-the-resolution-width-and-height-for-a-video-file-from-a-linux-co) please advise.  After [research](https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bvideo%5D%20terminal%20detail) the only Q&A returned is: [Terminal tool to join mp4 videos](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/135157/terminal-tool-to-join-mp4-videos)

Comment: Have you tried using `mdls`?

Comment: What is that?  I'm not familiar with it

Comment: From its manual page: "mdls -- lists the metadata attributes for the specified file"

Comment: would that list the frame rates and compression because the man page doesn't have much detail

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't just test `mdls` against a video file and see what it outputs!?